# Native library pre-loader is trying to load native SQLite library SQLite.Interop.dll"...

Tags: c#, sqlite

SQLite 1.0.104.0 From Nuget Package Manager.
.Net Framework 4.5.2
VS2015 community version
win 7 64 ultmate
platform target 64bit

I searched through this forum and none of the solution work for me.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 4):

I assume the question is:
Why do I get the error "Native library pre-loader is trying to load native SQLite library SQLite.Interop.dll"…"?

Answer:

This is not an error, and it is just reporting that the connection has started or restarted. If you are having issues with your sql there will likely be other errors below the "Native library pre-loader" message.